# Transform div board top

Tags: html, css

How can I transform CSS-div to look like the image http://screenshots.fr.sftcdn.net/fr/scrn/321000/321755/yu-gi-oh-online-3-12.jpg board?

And what is this kind of view called?

I played around some with `skew`, but did manage to find it.

```
.board {
    width: 325px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 300px;
transform: skew(5deg, 40deg);
}
```

Comment: This is CSS3's `perspective` property

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do

```css
#div {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    perspective: 300px;
}

#box
{
    display: inline-block; 
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
}

#row {
    background-color: blue;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <div id="box">
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
    <div id="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I place another row just below? Some big spacing is coming.

Comment: Last thing, If I add content in a box, i.e "A Box", in one of the row divs, they get messed up to.